# Почему другой пользователь обновляет репозиторий от имени моего аккаунта?

Tags: github

Почему пользователь KristiKanni создает и обновляет репозиторий от моего лица fabretti?

[image]

Comment: Вы про https://github.com/fabretti/Cherkizovo и https://github.com/KristiKanni/cherkizovo ? Думаю, такое можно сделать если при коммитах указывать автором другого человека, а гитхаб уже подхватит

Comment: Почему коммиты приписываются другому пользователю написано здесь: [Why are my commits linked to the wrong user?](https://help.github.com/en/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user)

Comment: @gil9red https://github.com/KristiKanni/fapg Репозиторий KristiKanni, а загрузил и коммиты все от лица fabretti. Хотя я даже не прикосался к этому репозиторию

Comment: @Эникейщик Спасибо, почитаю